# Who maintains the threadstates in Java from running to wait/blocking states

Tags: java, multithreading

As we know in Java Thread starts with calling of start method and when we call, `thread.wait()`. It goes from running to wait states and when we call sleep it doesn't.

My question is this: who manages that state transition from running to wait or block state? Is there any role of `threadLocal` in Java?

Comment: The JVM :) http://www.javatpoint.com/life-cycle-of-a-thread

Comment: As Alex pointed out below, the OS is responsible for blocking a thread.  `ThreadLocal` is a completely different idea.  I could see a JVM cache certain thread states for faster access, but most of the fine detail of thread execution (running, blocked, ready) is handled directly by the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread management is a domain of operation systems. It is the OS that puts a thread to a wait state and wakes it when needed. Of course there is a Java intermediate layer which translates the Java thread API to system calls. So you directly interact with the JVM, but on desktop systems it will implement threads using threads supported by the operation system.

Note that there may be different corner cases. For example you may have a bare metal system which runs a JVM without any OS. In this case thread support (if there is any) will be implemented by the JVM. There is also a concept of green threads which are similar to usual threads but are managed inside applications without OS support.

Comment: Hi Alexey as you said it is similar Green thread which is introduced in java 1.2 and later removed can you please share any resource.

Comment: I'm not familiar with implementation of that feature in Java, so I can't point you to a good documentation. But this is relatively popular idea which can be found in many modern languages. It can be called coroutines, greenlets, fibers, asyncs. The main idea is that if don't need fair scheduling, simultaneous execution and memory protection you can switch between such specific threads much faster inside the application. OS does not know about them, it thinks that you execute a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

> Who manages that state transition from running to wait or block state?
>   Is there any role of threadLocal in Java ?

JVM thread scheduler maintains the thread life cycle and different thread states (READY, RUNNING, WAIT, etc..) i.e., right from thread creation till thread termination. It is the thread scheduler which takes care of moving the thread states from one to another i.e., RUNNING to WAIT or RUNNING to READY etc..

As Alexey mentioned, at the low level the threads will be run by the Operating System (OS).

`ThreadLocal` object is local to each thread and can be used to store and retrieve the variables i.e, the **variables stored inside the `ThreadLocal` object are visible only to that thread** and can't be accessible for other threads.